# Setting up Titan and Cassandra - Could not instantiate storage manager class

Tags: java, groovy, cassandra, gremlin, titan

I've set up cassandra server (Datastax community edition) and it's running fine.

My **cassandra.yaml** has the following settings:

```
seeds: "127.0.0.1"
storage_port: 7000
rpc_port: 9160
```

When I do this in gremlin shell:

```
conf = new BaseConfiguration();
conf.setProperty("storage.backend","cassandra");
conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1");
conf.setProperty("storage.port",9160);
```

and,

```
g= TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate storage manager class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:215)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:97)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:398)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:78)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:60)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:46)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:60)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:67)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.main(Console.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:204)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryStorageException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:328)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.<init>(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:136)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.NoAvailableHostsException: NoAvailableHostsException: [host=None(0.0.0.0):0, latency=0(0), attempts=0] No hosts to borrow from
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.<init>(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:31)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.TokenAwareConnectionPoolImpl.newExecuteWithFailover(TokenAwareConnectionPoolImpl.java:74)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:229)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.executeSchemaChangeOperation(ThriftClusterImpl.java:131)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.addKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:252)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:323)
    ... 57 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you seen https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/Could$20not$20instantiate$20storage$20manager$20class%7Csort:relevance/aureliusgraphs/V-sMX6SMhe4/tz6lMRMWozkJ one???

Comment: 1) make sure you are running gremlin on the same machine as cassandra otherwise you need to adjust the host and if that does not help 2) try using "casssandrathrift" as the storage.backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. solution is compatible version check. I downloaded the latest version of cassandra and the error is gone.

apache-cassandra-1.2.5

titan-all-0.3.1